# Unable to Set Property of Undefined or Null reference

Tags: angular

I am trying to set a value to the properties of an Object, but everytime I am getting this error.

I've tried to implement the object inside a class and I also tried to implement and import an interface.

```
// In my interface I have put:
export interface Despesas {
  totalAlimentacao: string,
  totalHospedagem: string,
}

// And in my Class Service
import { Despesas } from '../interfaces/despesas'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DespesasService {

  @Input() objectDespesas: Despesas;

  constructor() { }

setDespesas() {
    this.objectDespesas.totalAlimentacao = "2";
  }

// I am calling setDespesas from other place and it is everything fine in the call
```

Comment: `this.objectDespesas` is null or undefined. Since it's an `@Input()`, some code using your service is not providing the object before calling `setDespesas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will always be `undefined` because you have specified the object as an `@Input`, which comes from a parent template, and services do not have associated templates.

`@Input` and `@Output` are for directives/components.

All you have to do is initialise the object in the constructor or in `onInit`

E.g.

```
this.objectDespesas = { }
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should try in the constructor of DespesasService to initialize the object

```
constructor()
{

  this.objectDespesas = {
     totalAlimentacao: '',
     totalHospedagem: ''
  }

}
```